# printing page removes some colors

Tags: javascript, html, printing

I have a page in my web app that looks like this:
[image: in application]

It is an image with some pinpoints on it.
But when I print this page using chromes print -> save as pdf function it looks like this

[image: in the pdf]

As you can see the color of the pinpoints is gone and they are just white. 
How come? How do I fix this?

Comment: Digital images verus print images use different color libraries - Print uses CMYK and digital uses RGB. It is possible the image is saved in an RGB format, where the teal color is not recognized the same way within the CMYK library that is used within PDFs.

Comment: the pinpoint uses a hex color (style="background-color: #00a6ff;") what format should it be?

Comment: According to https://www.colorhexa.com/00a6ff, the closest web safe color is #0099ff. You can also use the CMYK color scheme, which is 100, 35, 0, 0

Answer (score 0):

This problem might be solved by adjusting any media query css rule that specifically targets screen and not printer.
For example:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  body {
    background-color: lightblue;
  }
}
```

Would only apply the rule when viewed on screen.
To apply also to printer:

```
@media all and (max-width: 600px) {
  body {
    background-color: lightblue;
  }
}
```

Comment: I checked this but the pinpoint has his own element styling for color:
style="background-color: #00a6ff;" 

This color is a hex color. Should it use a different color format?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the way to fix this (atleast for chrome) is using:
-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;